# It is actually possible for a player to collect 99 Stars in one game?

Tags: mario-party

[According to The Cutting Room Floor](https://tcrf.net/Mario_Party), if you go to Toad in Mario Party (1) but you already have 99 Stars, he'll deny you the chance to get a 100th.

[image: screenshot of hacked situation]

Considering that the longest possible game is 50 turns, and there are very few opportunities to steal opponents' Stars, it seems impossible to achieve this without cheats. Is it?

Comment: I would lean towards the side of it being impossible, at 50 turns you would almost have to get 2 star's EVERY turn. This is seemingly impossible especially early in game. Even if you won every minigame, you would some how have to have extreme luck to hit multiple stars in every turn. Even if you stole stars, how could you possibly replenish your coins fast enough to buy 2 more the next turn? I think that picture has to be fake. Its one thing to get one player to 99 stars but all 4? No way..

Comment: The given image is "fake" in the sense that hacks were used to put everyone at 99 Stars for the sake of demonstrating the unique behaviour. The question is whether it's possible for the behaviour to be used without hacks, even if unlikely.